# Is there any alternative for android.net.rtp package

Tags: android

android.net.rtp provides APIs for RTP (Real-time Transport Protocol), allowing applications to manage on-demand or interactive data streaming right? But i am working on api 11. This package is available in api 12, so is there any alternative for this package

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but http://sourceforge.net/projects/jlibrtp/ might be helpful.